# Performance issues on iOs with css animations

Tags: ios, css

I have a html page containing a div that is moving in when clicking on a button by using css transition on the bottom attribute. (change of bottom value is done by jQuery) This is working fine in all browsers (including iOS on iPad). Now I am developing a second page that has to do the same thing. I copied all css properties and the jQuery function but there is always a choppy animation on iOS (only on iOS!!) when the div moves in.

I already tried solutions like:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

or

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

Nothing makes the animation be smooth like in the other page where I (as I think) completely have the same code.

Now I have no idea why there is a difference and how I can solve this. Did anyone already have some similar trouble and can give me some helpful advices for that?

Full code CSS:

```
.animationTestObject {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background-color: black;
   position: fixed;
   left: 100px;
   bottom: -100px;
   transition: bottom 500ms;
   -webkit-transition: bottom 500ms;
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

JS:

```
function startAnimation() {
   $(".animationTestObject").css('bottom', '100px');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a better performance while animating, try to avoid the [css properties that trigger a relayout](https://csstriggers.com/) (those marked with a purple tag).

In your case, you should animate the transform: translate property like so:

```
.animationTestObject {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 100px;
    bottom: -100px;
    transition: transform 500ms ease;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

function startAnimation() {
    $('.animationTestObject').css('transform', 'translate(0, -100px)');
}
```

Comment: This solution instantly worked without any performance struggle! Thank you!